# Why can't I delete duplicate enterprise app icon copy?

Tags: ios, iphone, enterprise

At first I found a problem that when some old users can't update app.They clicked the download link -> pop alert-> click "download",but there is no reaction, the app can't download. I felt anxious.

Then someone told me it is a iOS8 bug.The solution is that modify xxxx.plist(when download .ipa to need)'s bundleID,making a difference with the true bundleID.I found it is work!The users who can't download really can download!!!

But only briefly, I found another problem that ios7.0 users will show tow same app icons, the one is gray.And the gray app can't delete.The image is this [capture](http://www.mmprod.com/PICS/enterprise.jpg).I am very anxious.Can someone help me?

Comment: You changed its bundle id. But have you set correct provisioning profiles for enterprise app ?

Comment: @iOSNoob, yes, I have